# How to distribute a Native Messaging Host with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I developed an extension that communicates with a host (also developed by me), as provided by the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging example, and it works just fine.

Now I need to distribute my host with my extension and I couldn't find in Distributions how can I package my host along my extension. Are there any examples of how can I do it? Or must I distribute my host elsewhere?

Comment: Try including it in the extension, then use chrome.downloads API to download it in the default download directory and in its callback invoke chrome.downloads.open. Check the documentation and [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#downloads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I couldn't find in Distributions how can I package my host along my extension.

Support for this has been [requested and turned down](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321628) by Chrome developers.

I would recommend reading that thread for some insights in how native hosts are supposed to work according to them.

> Or must I distribute my host elsewhere?

That's the idea. You need an installer hosted somewhere else.

wOxxOm's proposal is not going to work seamlessly, since a Native host cannot function without registering it with the system (e.g. adding a registry key on Windows) - something an extension cannot trigger.

It's possible you can still follow the bundle-download-open route for an *installer*, but I imagine it may get frowned upon by Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Thanks, I'll distribute it somewhere else.